# Can not access variable on Popover template from Angularjs Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I'm using AngularJs version 1.5. I created a simple component to add comment

```
angular.module('myapp')
.component('comments', {
    templateUrl: "views/component/comments.html",
    bindings: { },
    controller: function ($http, $rootScope, $interval, $scope) {
        var ctrl = this
        ctrl.users = $rootScope.users;
        console.log(ctrl.users); // This variable had value
    }
})
```

Then, in the view, I place a button to show a Popover

```
<button popover-is-open="$ctrl.userListPopoverStatus" popover-title="Add User" uib-popover-template="'views/popover/order_select_user.html'" popover-placement="top" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="$ctrl.users"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-tags"></i></button>
```

My Popover template

```
<div class="row margintop-10">
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <table class="table table-striped small_table_user">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.searchText" placeholder="Search user" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $ctrl.users | filter:$ctrl.searchText">
            <td ng-click="pickUserProcess(user.id)">{{user.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
```

But seem like, the Bootstrap Popover can not access the $ctrl.users variable, so the list user not show at all. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this causes from angular dot issues.
Try:

```
var ctrl = {}
ctrl.users = $rootScope.users;
```